# Jackson cannot convert empty string value to enum

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I am looking for a handy solution with Jackson (2.8) to filter out fields pointing to empty String value before/during deserialization:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Guis {

public enum Context {
    SDS,
    NAVIGATION
}

public enum Layer {
    Library,
    Status,
    Drivingdata
}

// client code

 String s = "{\"context\":\"\",\"layer\":\"Drivingdata\"}";
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Guis o = mapper.readValue(s, Guis.class);
```

Error

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type cq.speech.rsi.api.Guis$Context from String "": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [SDS NAVIGATION] at [Source: {"context":"","layer":"Drivingdata"}; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: cq.speech.rsi.api.Guis["context"])
```

What else I tried... 
Ah this one

```
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

The error remains and apparently even googling around didn't help much...

**EDIT**

set DeserializationFeature does not work as exemplified above. For me the solution was eventually to add this snippet:

```
 mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true)
```

Comment: What do you expect `Context` to be after deserialization?

Comment: I am aware of the option to code customized deserializer in jackson. For my purpose, it would suffice either to ignore `Context` completely or `Context` is null.

Comment: This sounds like something worth opening a ticket for. I would naively expect "empty" on an enum to be mappable to null in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I was able to help. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ok, I removed the acknowledgment

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can enable `DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` for your mapper, its disabled by default. Only caveat to using this, it will treat all unknown including empty string as null for enum.

Comment: Another option is to enable READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE and use a default value

Comment: To add to debiasej comment: you will need to mark one of the enum values with @JsonEnumDefaultValue  https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE

Answer (score 18):

You can use a factory that returns a null value if the string doesn't match an enum literal:

```
public enum Context {
    SDS,
    NAVIGATION;

    @JsonCreator
    public static Context forName(String name) {
        for(Context c: values()) {
            if(c.name().equals(name)) { //change accordingly
                return c;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course the implementation can change according to your logic, but this allows the use of `null` values for the enum.

The `JsonCreator` annotation tells Jackson to call the method to get an instance for the string.